# Cluster people based on spatial coordinates with constraints

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a pandas dataframe `df`. The columns `latitude` and `longitude` represent the spatial coordinates of people.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"latitude": [49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.56643220000001, 49.5719721, 49.5748542, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.57586389999999, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.572026, 49.5727859, 49.5740071, 49.57500899999999, 49.5751017, 49.5751468, 49.5757358, 49.5659508, 49.56611359999999, 49.5680586, 49.568089, 49.5687609, 49.5699217, 49.572154, 49.5724688, 49.5733994, 49.5678048, 49.5702381, 49.5707702, 49.5710414, 49.5711228, 49.5713705, 49.5723685, 49.5725714, 49.5746149, 49.5631496, 49.5677449, 49.572268, 49.5724273, 49.5726773, 49.5739391, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.57586389999999, 49.5729483, 49.57321150000001, 49.5733375, 49.5745175, 49.574758, 49.5748055, 49.5748103, 49.5751023, 49.57586389999999, 49.56643220000001, 49.5678048, 49.5679685, 49.568089, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.5724688, 49.5740071, 49.5757358, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.5642962, 49.56643220000001, 49.5679685, 49.570056, 49.5619579, 49.5724688, 49.5745175, 49.5748055, 49.5748055, 49.5748542, 49.5748542, 49.5751023, 49.5751023],
"longitude": [10.9995758, 10.9995758, 10.9999593, 10.9910787, 11.0172739, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 11.0244747, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9907713, 10.9885155, 10.9873742, 10.9861229, 10.9879312, 10.9872357, 10.9920322, 10.9873409, 10.9894231, 10.9882496, 10.9894035, 10.9887881, 10.984756, 10.9911384, 10.9850981, 10.9852771, 10.9954673, 10.9993329, 10.9965937, 10.9949475, 10.9912959, 10.9939141, 10.9916605, 10.9983124, 10.992722, 11.0056254, 10.9954016, 11.017472, 11.0180908, 11.0181911, 11.0175466, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0244747, 11.0200454, 11.019251, 11.0203055, 11.0183162, 11.0252416, 11.0260046, 11.0228523, 11.0243391, 11.0244747, 10.9999593, 10.9954673, 10.9982288, 10.9894035, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9850981, 10.9873742, 10.9920322, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 11.0039476, 10.9999593, 10.9982288, 10.9993409, 10.9995758, 10.9850981, 11.0183162, 11.0260046, 11.0260046, 11.0172739, 11.0172739, 11.0243391, 11.0243391]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to cluster people based on their spatial coordinates. Each cluster must contain exactly 9 people. However, I want to avoid that people with the same spatial coordinates slip into the same cluster. This can happen, because the dataset contains some location coordinates that are exactly the same and therefore automatically assigned to the same cluster. So the goal is to prevent exactly that when clustering. It may be necessary to automatically move the persons to an adjacent cluster in a subsequent process.

To cluster the people I used `k-means-constrained` with `!pip install k-means-constrained`.

```
from k_means_constrained import KMeansConstrained

coordinates = np.column_stack((df["latitude"], df["longitude"]))

# Define the number of clusters and the number of points per cluster
n_clusters = len(df) // 9
n_points_per_cluster = 9

# Perform k-means-constrained clustering
kmc = KMeansConstrained(n_clusters=n_clusters, size_min=n_points_per_cluster, size_max=n_points_per_cluster, random_state=42)
kmc.fit(coordinates)

# Get cluster assignments
df["cluster"] = kmc.labels_
```

To validate the result I check how many people have been clustered in the same cluster although they have same spatial coordinates:

```
duplicate_rows = df[df.duplicated(subset=["cluster", "latitude", "longitude"], keep=False)]
duplicate_indices = duplicate_rows.index.tolist()

# Group by specified columns and count occurrences
count_occurrences = df.iloc[duplicate_indices].groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', 'cluster']).size().reset_index(name='count')

print("Number of rows with identical values in specified columns:")
print(count_occurrences)
```

For example the print-statement looks like this:

```
Number of rows with identical values in specified columns:
           latitude                   longitude        cluster  count
0     49.5619579000000030      10.9995758000000006        0      2
1     49.5748054999999965      11.0260046000000003        9      2
2     49.5748541999999972      11.0172738999999993        9      2
3     49.5751022999999975      11.0243391000000006        9      2
4     49.5757357999999968      10.9920322000000006        0      3
5     49.5758150999999998      11.0249866000000001        7      8
```

In total we have (8+3+2+2+2+2) people who are clusters with a neighbor from the same building. I want to minimize this number. `count = 2` or less works fine for me. Its not perfect, but I can deal with that. But `count > 2` (for example index 5) is not okay. Too many people with same spatial coordinates in the same cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over-complicating the solution here.

Firstly, you should figure out how you want to deal with duplicated points if they are a problem for you. There's not necessarily a 'correct' answer here, since it will depend on what you're doing and what you want.

Secondly, it's probably not appropriate to use clustering and fix precisely the cluster size. Since this can lead to weird clusterings where you force a point to be a part of a distant cluster just because a closer one is 'full'. I think you probably need to refine what you're trying to do to address this (it's a problem with my solution below too).

In terms of getting unique clusters of specificall 9 points in close proximity you can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
"latitude": [49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.56643220000001, 49.5719721, 49.5748542, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.5757358, 49.57586389999999, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.572026, 49.5727859, 49.5740071, 49.57500899999999, 49.5751017, 49.5751468, 49.5757358, 49.5659508, 49.56611359999999, 49.5680586, 49.568089, 49.5687609, 49.5699217, 49.572154, 49.5724688, 49.5733994, 49.5678048, 49.5702381, 49.5707702, 49.5710414, 49.5711228, 49.5713705, 49.5723685, 49.5725714, 49.5746149, 49.5631496, 49.5677449, 49.572268, 49.5724273, 49.5726773, 49.5739391, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.57586389999999, 49.5729483, 49.57321150000001, 49.5733375, 49.5745175, 49.574758, 49.5748055, 49.5748103, 49.5751023, 49.57586389999999, 49.56643220000001, 49.5678048, 49.5679685, 49.568089, 49.57182530000001, 49.5719721, 49.5724688, 49.5740071, 49.5757358, 49.5748542, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5758151, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.5642962, 49.56643220000001, 49.5679685, 49.570056, 49.5619579, 49.5724688, 49.5745175, 49.5748055, 49.5748055, 49.5748542, 49.5748542, 49.5751023, 49.5751023],
"longitude": [10.9995758, 10.9995758, 10.9999593, 10.9910787, 11.0172739, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 10.9920322, 11.0244747, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9907713, 10.9885155, 10.9873742, 10.9861229, 10.9879312, 10.9872357, 10.9920322, 10.9873409, 10.9894231, 10.9882496, 10.9894035, 10.9887881, 10.984756, 10.9911384, 10.9850981, 10.9852771, 10.9954673, 10.9993329, 10.9965937, 10.9949475, 10.9912959, 10.9939141, 10.9916605, 10.9983124, 10.992722, 11.0056254, 10.9954016, 11.017472, 11.0180908, 11.0181911, 11.0175466, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0244747, 11.0200454, 11.019251, 11.0203055, 11.0183162, 11.0252416, 11.0260046, 11.0228523, 11.0243391, 11.0244747, 10.9999593, 10.9954673, 10.9982288, 10.9894035, 10.9910398, 10.9910787, 10.9850981, 10.9873742, 10.9920322, 11.0172739, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 11.0249866, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 11.0039476, 10.9999593, 10.9982288, 10.9993409, 10.9995758, 10.9850981, 11.0183162, 11.0260046, 11.0260046, 11.0172739, 11.0172739, 11.0243391, 11.0243391]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def grouping(lat_lon: np.ndarray, df: pd.core.frame.DataFrame, results: list):
    # First calculate the distance from a given point to all the rest
    distances = ((df - lat_lon)**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5
    # Sort these values so that they are closest -> furthest
    distances = distances.sort_values()
    # Take the top 9 (this will include the point itself
    top_9 = distances.index.values[:9]
    # Store the results in a list
    results.append(top_9)
    # Remove the values that are now in a cluster from
    # the dataframe, so that you don't add points to
    # multiple clusters
    df = df.drop(index = top_9)
    
    # Then, while there is still data left to cluster
    if len(df) != 0:
        # recurse this function with the next lat-lon point
        return grouping(df.iloc[0].values, df, results)
    # Otherwise if there is no data left
    else:
        return results

tmp_df = df.copy(deep=True)
clusters = grouping(tmp_df.iloc[0].values, tmp_df, [])

print(clusters)
```

Output:

```
[array([ 0, 81, 72,  1, 74, 73, 75, 78,  2]),
 array([ 3, 59, 10, 58,  9, 24, 11, 33, 31]),
 array([ 4, 87, 86, 63, 42, 41, 83, 48, 40]),
 array([ 5,  6,  7, 17, 62, 35, 15, 12, 32]),
 array([ 8, 53, 44, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66]),
 array([13, 61, 16, 14, 26, 60, 25, 82, 23]),
 array([18, 19, 20, 21, 57, 22, 37, 55, 27]),
 array([28, 80, 79, 56, 34, 29, 54, 30, 77]),
 array([36, 76, 38, 39, 46, 45, 47, 51, 52]),
 array([43, 64, 65, 88, 89, 49, 50, 84, 85])]
```

These results should be organised with the initial point in the 0th position - except in the case where there are duplicates, in which case there may be some issues (though it will probably be fine based on how we choose the initial points).

To demonstrate the problem with fixing 9 points per group:

```py
for idx, vals in enumerate(clusters):
    yx = df.iloc[vals].values
    plt.scatter(yx[:,1], yx[:,0], c=f'C{idx}')

plt.show()
```

Examine how the red cluster is split around the orange one, and the yellow/green is split across a large spatial distance.

[image]

It's possible that these issues can be mitigated by changing the order of the points for the cluster (e.g., shuffle them, and re-run until you get something that looks good), but it could become labourious if you have a lot of data. You could automate this by creating a way to identify it. E.g., you might create a geopandas dataframe with the points and form a convex hull for each cluster and check for overlap - shuffle and repeat clustering if there is. But it won't be particularly efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed approach. Unfortunately your approach results in many clusters with people who share same values in latitude and longitude. My goal is to minimize this number. I know, to fix cluster size is not ideal if you aim for optimal clusters. But in my case, a fix cluster size is very important. Its fine for me, if the distances between points are not at the perfect minimum. It is more important that both clusters are relatively clean in terms of direct neighbors and cluster size is exactly 9.